# Limit polar graph with angle measurements

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm currently working on this picture, and here's the code. It's to show multiplication of complex numbers in the first quadrant, showing what happens to the length and the angle.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
        xmin=0,
        xmax=90,
        ymax=3,
        xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^{\circ}$,
        ytick={0,1,2,3v},
        yticklabel style={yshift=-13pt},
        grid=both,
        minor grid style={dashed,black!25},
        major grid style=black,
        minor tick num=1]
        \addplot[->,red,very thick] plot coordinates {(0,0) (15,1.5)} node[right] {$z$};
        \addplot[->,blue,very thick] plot coordinates {(0,0) (45,2)} node[right] {$v$};
        \addplot[->,purple,very thick] plot coordinates {(0,0) (60,3)} node[left] {$zv$};
        \addplot[->,blue,dashed,very thick] plot coordinates {(0,0) (45,3)} node[left] {$\left| z \right| v$};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The code was based on what I could find here but I'm trying to adapt it to what I had before (even though it wasn't as nice):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\draw (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above] {$Im$} (-03,0)--(3,0) node[right] {$Re$};
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (3) circle (2) circle (1);
\coordinate (a) at (30:1.5);
\coordinate (b) at (45:2);
\coordinate (c) at (75:3);
\coordinate (o) at (0:0);
\coordinate (x) at (0:1.5);
\draw (a) [blue] node[above right] {$z$};
\draw (b) [red] node[right] {$v$};
\draw (c) [purple] node[above right] {$zv$};
\draw (0,0)--(a) [blue, thick];
\draw (0,0)--(b) [red, thick];
\draw (0,0)--(c) [purple, thick];
\draw[dashed, red, thick] (0:0)--(45:3) node[above right] {$\left| z \right| v$};
\end{scope}
\pic[draw,dashed,blue,ultra thicangle radius=0.9cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=x--o--a};
\pic[draw,dashed,red,ultra thick,angle radius=0.8cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=x--o--b};
\pic[draw,dashed,purple,ultra thick,angle radius=0.7cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=x--o--c};
\draw (15:1) [blue] node[right] {$\theta$};
\draw (48:1) [red] node[right] {$\phi$};
\draw (76:1.1) [purple] node[above right] {$\theta+\phi$};
\draw (0:1) [black] node[below] {$1$};
\draw (0:2) [black] node[below] {$2$};
\draw (0:3) [black] node[below] {$3$};
\fill[blue] (a) circle (2pt);
\fill[red] (b) circle (2pt);
\fill[purple] (c) circle (2pt);
\fill[red] (45:3) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I get "circles" for the angle measurements in the first section of code? I'll also need to remove the degrees and make it into "Im" and "Re"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=12cm}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
        xmin=0,
        xmax=90,
        ymax=3,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick={0,1,2,3},
        yticklabel style={yshift=-13pt},
        grid=both,
        minor grid style={dashed,black!25},
        major grid style=black,
        minor tick num=1,clip=false]
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) coordinate (O)-- (0,3.5) coordinate(x) node[below] {$\operatorname{Re}z$};
        \draw[-stealth] (O) -- (90,3.5) coordinate(y) node[left] {$\operatorname{Im}z$};
        \begin{scope}[,red,very thick,-stealth,shorten >=1.5pt]
         \draw[blue]  (O) -- (15,1.5) node[bullet,label=right:{$z$}](z){};
         \draw[red] (O) -- (45,2) node[bullet,label=right:{$v$}](v){};
         \draw[purple] (O) -- (60,3) node[bullet,label=right:{$z\,v$}](zv){};
         \draw[red,dashed]  (0,0) -- (45,3) node[bullet,label=right:{$\left| z \right| v$}]{};
        \end{scope}
        \pic[draw,dashed,blue,thick,angle radius=1.4cm,
            angle eccentricity=1.1,pic text={$\theta$}] {angle=x--O--z};
        \pic[draw,dashed,red,thick,angle radius=1.9cm,
            angle eccentricity=1.1,pic text={$\phi$}] {angle=x--O--v};
        \pic[draw,dashed,purple,thick,angle radius=2.4cm,
            angle eccentricity=1.2,pic text={$\theta+\phi$}] {angle=x--O--zv};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great :D